# PHPunit test not working

Tags: php, zend-framework, powershell, phpunit, include-path

I'm trying to learn zend framework 2 with this phpunit added, but I cannot get it work. I've followed the steps in the official zf2 tutorial (http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/user-guide/unit-testing.html) and now I'm facing some kind of error message clueless

```
Warning: require_once(File/Iterator/Autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\php\pear\PHPUnit\Autoload.php on line 64

Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'File/Iterator/Autoload.php' (include_path='.;\php\zend_framework\library;\php\pear\PEAR') in C:\xampp\php\pear\PHPUnit\Autoload.php on line 64
PS C:\xampp\htdocs\new103\module\Application\test>
```

Answer (score 0):

Needed to change the php.ini `include_path` to list of absolute paths, phpunit can be ran now.